Do Zipair transpacific flights have hot water?
I will be flying with Zipair soon, from the US to Japan. I am excited to fly a discount airline across the Pacific. As they charge for food & beverage service, I am preparing to bring my own food with me. As of right now, I plan to bring instant noodles. However, if there is no water, this won't work.
Does Zipair have hot water available on the flight? And, if they do, is it free?
I have looked extensively on the Zipair website, and see no conclusive statement about hot water. I watched some of the YouTube videos of people flying on Zipair (they are fun videos!) but somehow this critical topic is not covered.

Have you contacted Zipair and asked them ?

Having flown Zipair, they sell hot drinks so they definitely have hot water.  Whether they will give it to you for free so you can make your own food (which is usually not permitted by budget airlines) is a different question.

Funny story: on the ultra long hauls (EWR<->HKG, 16 hours) United used to an extra meal/snack service half way through. If you were lucky enough to sit up front, it was typically a nice wonton soup and a salad. Of course that got axed but they set up some (low quality) snacks in the business galley. One of them was indeed some instant Ramen with hot water. It was pretty much the cheapest instant Ramen there is., which seems ironic for one of the most expensive tickets they sell

@Hilmar it’s indeed quite ironic that I can get a better meal from Taco Bell at the airport for $10 than what the airline will serve me on a $2000 flight :-)

Zipair charges for water. I couldn't find hot water on the menu, but even if they have they will very likely charge you for it.
My go-to meal options for those flights are foods that can be eaten cold or at room temperature and won't spoil so fast: tamales, onigiri, spam sushi, sandwiches, hard boiled eggs, cheese cubes, the list goes on...
If you really want to prepare instant noodles you can take a thermos bottle (empty) with you, fill and heat it at the airport with one of these portable heaters:
 
Chances are you can't use them inside the plane (even though there might be power outlets, they likely won't provide enough power for a water heater).
And keep in mind when boarding a budget long-haul flight that you should board the plane with at least 1.5 liters of water with you, even more if you are doing instant noodles.

I took the liberty of emphasising the "at the airport" bit, you certainly don't want to either fill the bottle or try to heat it up in the aircraft.

Would that even pass security?

The ones with long metal pipes might not. However, I can't see any reason for the ones with small heating elements covered in plastic to not pass.

I did the flight last week. Zip Air is fantastic; a very comfortable flight. I didn't find any hot water; and they charge for water.

What did you bring to eat?
